# Twitter Bootstrap, how to know the current media query?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, layout, media-queries

As we know Twitter Bootstrap manages by default 4 layout states through media-queries: *xs*, *sm*, *md*, *lg*.

I came with the need of knowing in which of the above media-queries was my browser, and resizing the browser-screen until I was moving from one media-query to another.

I would like to know which is the actual media-query Twitter Bootstrap is using, it is OK if I have to inject some html, css, js code in my website.

Comment: well.. every normal browser-addon shows you the viewport, so you actually now in which "query" you are if you know bootstrap?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes with the same concern I solved adding this peace of code at some point of my html code:

```
<div id="media_query_alerts">
  <div class="alert alert-warning visible-xs-block" role="alert">media-query xs</div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning visible-sm-block" role="alert">media-query sm</div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning visible-md-block" role="alert">media-query md</div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning visible-lg-block" role="alert">media-query lg</div>
</div>
```